# With Manifest v3 how can I adjust User-Agent

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension with version 3.  I am trying to use chrome.declarativeNetRequest to set the User-Agent header, but seems like there's no effect.  I can block the website loading, so i have most of it there.  with modifying headers, is there a restriction on User-Agent?

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
        "type": "modifyHeaders",
        "responseHeaders": [
          { "header": "User-Agent", "operation": "set", "value": "v2" }
        ]
      },
    "condition": {"urlFilter": "localhost", "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
  }
```

]

Comment: It [should just work](https://crbug.com/36706#c17) so there's either a bug in Chrome or your code is incorrect, in both cases the question is unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: I found site https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending to test what my headers are.  I am setting user-agent to something different, but navigator.userAgent is not giving me the value I set.  Is that to be expected?

Comment: navigator.userAgent is a client-side JavaScript API that is not related to the HTTP headers sent to the server.

Comment: Thank you, I was overcomplicating the problem.